# How do you change the Value component of the color of a sprite renderer in Unity through code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the color of the sprite using the HSV values. Whenever I press play, the sprite always goes to white and the HSV values are all 0.

When printed in the console, the HSV values are the ones I inputted, but the values in the Color Picker UI are 0 when I hit play.

I've scoured the internet and the Unity manual but cannot seem to find any answers.

Here is my code:

```
[SerializeField] float hue; //246
[SerializeField] float saturation; //48
[SerializeField] float value; //25

SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
CollectHearts collectHearts;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    collectHearts = FindObjectOfType<CollectHearts>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ChangeColor();
}

private void ChangeColor()
{
    float newHue = hue / 100;
    float newSaturation = saturation / 100;
    float newValue = value / 100;


    spriteRenderer.color = Color.
                HSVToRGB(newHue, newSaturation, newValue + collectHearts.GetHearts());

    Debug.Log(hue + " " + saturation + " " + value);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters of `Color.HSVToRGB()` have to be **between 0.0 ~ 1.0**
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.HSVToRGB.html

So, the value of hue should be changed.

```
[SerializeField] float hue; //246
[SerializeField] float saturation; //48
[SerializeField] float value; //25

float newHue = hue / 100;
```